# How to filter data by group and remove values if a condition is given in R?

Tags: r, database, dplyr, data-manipulation

I want to filter a database using dplyr in R, but remove those rows that differ in a magnitude of 1e-5. My data is like this:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Group1 | 3.02e-90 |
| Group1 | 3.02e-89 |
| Group2 | 3.02e-90 |
| Group2 | 3.02e-90 |
| Group2 | 3.02e-10 |
| Group3 | 3.02e-88 |
| Group3 | 3.02e-90 |
| Group3 | 3.02e-89 |

In this data I would like to remove row number 5 from group2 (3.02e-10) because it differs from the rest of the values in group2 by an order of magnitude of 1e-5. In other words, I would like to be able to remove all observations that differ from the rest by 5 decimal units per group and keep the rest. I have tried different codes but nothing works for me, I have only been able to calculate the differences with :

```
df<- input %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(difference = c(0,diff(Value)))
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: While I can see using a combination of `outer` and `rowSums` to determine differences between values, do you need to deal with groups that have (say) equal numbers at `3e-90` and `3e-10`? I'm inferring that you'd prefer to keep the values that are anomalous from the others, but if it's the same (or nearly the same) count for the higher and lower values, it may not be quite as obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do what I wanted, the solution was simple. Count the number of decimal places in the value column:

```
countdec <- function(x) {
 if ((x %% 1) != 0) {
   strs <- strsplit(as.character(format(x, scientific = F)), "\\.")
    n <- nchar(strs[[1]][2])
  } else {
   n <- 0
  }
  return(n) 
}
```

apply the function:

```
input$ndec <-  sapply(input$value, FUN = countdec )
```

then, extract the difference in number of decimal places:

```
library(dplyr)
df<- input %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 mutate(diff = ndec - ndec[1], 
 diff = replace(diff, row_number() == 1, NA))
```

Then change NA for zeros:

```
df$diff[is.na(df$diff)] <- 0
```

multiply by -1 to obtain positive values:

```
df$diff<-  df$diff *-1
```

Finally, filter out those rows that have decimal values less than 5.

```
df %>% filter(diff <= 5)
```